# fascia compound angles

Tags: exterior, carpentry, trim-carpentry

Alright so hopefully I can explain this properly.

I'm replacing a fascia board where the corner can't be a straight cut. There is one board that spans the "bottom" of the roof and one that goes up the gable.

The long board on the bottom I cut to a inner 45deg bevel. This board, due to the structure of the house, does not sit at a perfect 90 with the roof plywood.

I figured, with the "bottom" board installed, I can use a t-bevel with the long metal side flush with the inside of the roof ply and the back end against the back of the "bottom" board I can get the 2nd angle I need to cut the gable with.

As such the gable will be cut at a 45 bevel and a miter of whatever the t-bevel yields.

Is this a correct approach? Better ways?

[image]

Comment: Alex, You could improve your question considerably if you were to add some type of drawing or photo to better illustrate the scenario at hand.

Comment: is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, The pictures really help to explain what you are making a query about.

Comment: its completed, the t-bevel method worked but required some miter tweaking. it was a major pidas - next time going to hire a carpenter haha.